# Seeking an English Pronounciation program

Tags: windows, educational, language

My mother language is not English. I want to reduce my accent and improve my fluency.

The details: I want to read a sentence and record it. The software should then score it by comparing it to standard US English, and give my a pass if the score is high enough.

Don't recommend Rosetta Stone. The software is good but it is only for very elementary level.

The software must run on Windows; Windows 7 is preferred.

Comment: And which "standard English would that be"? Oxford English? Queen's English? Boston? Texas? New York? Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation  My advice to you is to find the nearest English/Irish pub & start chatting. That's how I learn my foreign languages. But,t hen, I am probably more interested in being understood that in having a perfect accent. YMMV